# error in allocating pointer of node in recursive binary tree generation

Tags: c++, pointers, ubuntu, recursion, binary-tree

I'm doing this project where I am supposed to create a balanced binary tree using randomly chosen nodes, where a node can be a math operator or a constant. The function createRandomNode(bool, node*) basically returns a randomly chosen node.

The thing is, when I run this piece of code in VS, it can run perfectly well. However, when I bring it over to Ubuntu, the pointer value to the returned node is changed when return retFtn is executed in the else segment.

So for instance in VS, the tree will basically look something like below, where I used the address stored in the pointer to represent each node:

```
                             0x0543b
                            /       \
                      0x0544c       0x0456d
                     /       \     /       \
                 0x0342d  0x0453c 0x665f  0x893a
```

For each node, I can view its value and label when running in VS. However when running in Ubuntu, the moment 0x0453c is returned and the recursive function returns to retFtn->right (where retFtn is now 0x0543b since 0x0544c has already completed), 0x0544c changes to some weird address and I can no longer see this node's value and label, although I can still see it before 0x0453c is returned.

Below is the code in question.

```
node* createRandomTree(int depth, node* parent)
{
    if (depth > 1)
    {
        node* retFtn = createRandomNode(true, parent);
        retFtn->left = createRandomTree(depth - 1, retFtn);
        retFtn->right = createRandomTree(depth - 1, retFtn);
        if (retFtn->parent == NULL)
            return retFtn;
    }
    else
    {
        node* retFtn = createRandomNode(false, parent);
        return retFtn;
    }
}
```

I hope I have explained clearly, thank you for your help! :)

/************************************************************************/
EDIT:

Below is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example which can recreate the problem in Ubuntu 16.04 (strangely, the problem does not occur when running in VS):

main.cpp:

```
#include "node.h"
#include "random.h"
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char * const argv[])
{
    node* createdTree = createRandomTree(3, NULL);
    std::cout << createdTree << endl;
    inOrder(createdTree);
}
```

random.cpp:

```
#include "random.h"

void inOrder(node* tree)
{
    if (!tree)
        return;
    cout << "(";
    inOrder(tree->left);
    cout << tree->label;
    inOrder(tree->right);
    cout << ")";
}

node* createRandomTree(int depth, node* parent)
{
    if (depth > 1)
    {
        node* retFtn = createRandomNode(true, parent); //isOperator==true
        retFtn->left = createRandomTree(depth - 1, retFtn);
        retFtn->right = createRandomTree(depth - 1, retFtn);
        if (retFtn->parent == NULL)
            return retFtn;
    }
    else
    {
        node* retFtn = createRandomNode(false, parent); //isOperator==true
        return retFtn;
    }
}

node* createRandomNode(bool isOperator, node* parent)
{
    int randn = -1;
    node* retFtn = NULL;

    if (isOperator)
        randn = 1;
    else
        randn = 0;

    switch (randn)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            retFtn = new ConstantValueNode(parent);
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            retFtn = new AddNode(parent);
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            cout << "invalid random number\n\n\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    return retFtn;
}
```

random.h

```
#ifndef random_H
#define random_H

#include "node.h"

node* createRandomNode(bool isOperator, node* parent);
node* createRandomTree(int depth, node* parent);
void inOrder(node* tree);
#endif
```

node.cpp:

```
#include "node.h"

/***************/
/*Constant Node*/
/***************/
ConstantValueNode::ConstantValueNode(node* retFtn)
{
    left=NULL;
    right=NULL;
    negate_Or_Not = false;
    constVal = rand()% 21 + (-10);
    key_value = constVal;
    parent = retFtn;
    label = "Constant";
};

ConstantValueNode::ConstantValueNode(double preSetVal)
{
    left=NULL;
    right=NULL;
    negate_Or_Not = false;
    constVal = preSetVal;
    key_value = constVal;
    label = "Constant";
};

double ConstantValueNode::eval(map<string,double> inputMapping)
{
    if (negate_Or_Not) //negation is true
        return !constVal;
    else
        return constVal;
}

ConstantValueNode* ConstantValueNode::clone(node* parent_clone)
{
    ConstantValueNode* retTree = new ConstantValueNode(key_value);
    if (parent_clone != NULL)
        retTree->parent = parent_clone;
    else
        retTree->parent = NULL;
    return retTree;
}

string ConstantValueNode::getLabel()
{
    return label;
}

/**********/
/*Add Node*/
/**********/
AddNode::AddNode()
{
    label = "AddNode";
    negate_Or_Not = NULL; //will be false by default
}
AddNode::AddNode(node* retFtn)
{
    label = "AddNode";
    negate_Or_Not = NULL;
    parent = retFtn;
}
double AddNode::eval(map<string,double> inputMapping)
{
    if (left && right)
        return left->eval(inputMapping) + right->eval(inputMapping);
    else
    {
        cout << "left and right not defined in add"<<endl;
        return -1.0;
    }
}

AddNode* AddNode::clone(node* parent_clone)
{
    AddNode* retNode = new AddNode();
    retNode->left = left->clone(retNode);
    retNode->right = right->clone(retNode);
    if (parent_clone != NULL)
        retNode->parent = parent_clone;
    else
        retNode->parent = NULL;
    return retNode;
}

string AddNode::getLabel()
{
    return label;
}
```

node.h:

```
#ifndef Node_H
#define Node_H
#include<iostream>
#include<map>

using std::string; //This will allow you to use "string" as an unqualified name
                  //(resolving to "std::string")
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::map;

class node
{
    // Virtual function can be overriden and the pure virtual must be implemented.
    // virtual void Function() = 0; is a pure virtual. The "= 0" indicates is purity
    public:
        bool negate_Or_Not;
        string label;
        int key_value;
        node* left;
        node* right;
        node* parent;
        virtual double eval(map<string,double> inputMapping)=0;
        virtual node* clone(node* clone)=0;
        virtual string getLabel()=0;
};

class ConstantValueNode : public node
{
    double constVal;
    public:
        ConstantValueNode(node* retFtn);
        ConstantValueNode(double preSetVal);
        virtual double eval(map<string,double> inputMapping);
        virtual ConstantValueNode* clone(node* clone);
        virtual string getLabel();
};

class AddNode : public node
{
    public:
        AddNode();
        AddNode(node* retFtn);
        virtual double eval(map<string,double> inputMapping);
        virtual AddNode* clone(node* clone);
        virtual string getLabel();
};
#endif
```

Makefile:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11
# ****************************************************
main: main.o node.o random.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o main main.o node.o random.o

main.o: main.cpp node.h random.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c main.cpp

node.o: node.h 
random.o: node.h random.h
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: You have a possible execution path where the function returns some undefined value: if(...== NULL) return ...;    else ? return what?

Comment: @NathanOliver hmmm actually, i did use the debugger and set breakpoints for every single line in the code, and that's how I realised the address 0x0544c changes exactly at the line of retFtn->right, after returning retFtn(0x0453c) in the else segment, thus I couldn't wrap my head around what went wrong. :(

Comment: @programmer Okay.  Then you are going to need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @GiacomoDegliEsposti hmmm I don't quite understand what you meant? Do I need to handle some conditions in the else segment?

Comment: @programmer -- What do you return if the `retFtn->parent` is not NULL?  The previous comment is right -- you have undefined behavior since you return who-knows-what if it isn't NULL.  Usually a compiler would warn you that not all paths return a value.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie hmmm I've tried running if (retFtn->parent==NULL) but the error persists.

Comment: @NathanOliver Hi! I've edited the question to provide an example!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `createRandomTree(int depth, node* parent)` with `depth>1` and `parent!=NULL`, this function doesn't hit any `return` statement. So `createRandomTree` is executed till the end, then control is passed back to caller with no guaranteed return value provided. So `createRandomTree(3, NULL);` leads to `retFtn->left = createRandomTree(3 - 1, retFtn);` where random garbage is written to `retFtn->left` as a result.

I strongly recommend you to pay more attention to compiler warnings:

> random.cpp:29:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

---

PS you might be insterested why the hell does it work on VS. Don't know exact reason (it can be investigated by inspecting assembly code, but I neither have environment nor want to dig into it right now), but the general answer is "by chance". I see two possible ways:

1. compiler threw out `if (retFtn->parent == NULL)` check as useless (doesn't change anything) and costly (branching slows execution due to CPU conveyor architecture)
2. There are a lot of [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), which specify the way to pass return value to caller. The fastest is passing value via CPU registers. I can imagine the situation, when `retFtn` is stored in CPU register for calculations within function and on function exit it looks as if `retFtn` was returned. I had similar case on MIPS architecture.

Feel free to check exact reason and share with us.

Comment: thanks for the help! Managed to solve the problem :)